# How to create the shadow of material-like table view cells?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, shadow

I am trying to make my table view cells look "material". Here is something similar to what I want to do ([source](https://material.io/design/components/data-tables.html#behavior)):

[image]

Note that there is a shadow around the whole table view in the above image. What I want is that shadow, but **applied to each table view cell**, instead of the whole table view.

I first designed my cell in an XIB file. I put a `UIView` called `containerView` as a subview of the content view. I added constraints so that the `containerView` has a top, bottom, left, right margin of 8. This is so that the `containerView` is a little smaller than the content view, so that the shadow I put on it will be visible.

I also added a `UILabel` called `label` as the subview of `containerView` to show some text.

This is the `UITableViewCell` subclass:

```
class QueueItemCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var container: UIView!

    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        ...
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        ...
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        container.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        container.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        container.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3, height: 9)
        container.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        container.layer.cornerRadius = 4
        container.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: container.bounds, cornerRadius: 4).cgPath
        selectionStyle = .none
    }
}
```

There is nothing special about the data source and delegate methods except that I set the cells' height to 61 in `heightForRowAt`.

When I run the app, I got something like this:

[image]

The shadow on the bottom and left edges are quite good. But the right edge is a total disaster. The top edge also does not have a shadow, which is undesirable. I tried to do trial and error with `shadowPath` and `shadowOffset` but there's always one or two edges that looks bad.

How can I achieve a shadow on all edges of the cell, as shown in the first image?

Comment: I don't think you would need shadow path for adding simple shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `awakeFromNib` you have wrong view size. You need to move `container.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: container.bounds, cornerRadius: 4).cgPath` into `layoutSubviews`

or remove this code

```
container.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: container.bounds, cornerRadius: 4).cgPath
```

so shadow will be configured automatically

Comment: Moving it to `layoutSubviews` produces the same result as before, but removing it and changing `shadowOffset` to 0 works. I never knew `shadowPath` is optional!

Comment: you also could try `UIBezierPath(rect:)` instead of `UIBezierPath(roundedRect:)`